# Reason to SIGTERM jobs in case the shell is closed

Tags: bash

I have seen `trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT` in shell scripts which sends *SIGTERM* to all the jobs of the shell when this shell closes. If one executes a bash script, then new bash shell is started. For example here user executes `./trap_test.sh` and this creates a bash instance with PID `98959`:

```
 | |     |-+= 05624 user /usr/local/bin/bash
 | |     | \-+= 98959 user /bin/bash ./trap_test.sh
 | |     |   \--- 98960 user sleep 10
```

Under which circumstances it is possible that job is still running while the parent shell is closed? In the example above if I kill PID 98959 then PID 98960 is killed automatically. `trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT` seems to be useless to me as all the child processes should be killed anyway when the shell itself is closed.

Comment: " In the example above if I kill PID 98959 then PID 98960 is killed automatically" - are you sure about this - I cannot replicate this with bash and SIGTERM

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I'm afraid the `sleep 10` simply finished at the time when I sent the _SIGTERM_ to `98959`. If I use longer sleep time and kill the PID `98959`, then PID `1` becomes the parent process ID of `98960`. In a nutshell, `trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT` is not useless.

Answer (score 2):

If the sub process is started with nohup it will live on after the parent shell exits/dies, that is after all the purpose of the nohup command.

Other possibility is if the script or process handles the kill signal(s) (obviously not kill -9) and ignores it, then if you start it as a background task it will not die when the current shell exits..

example:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 function trap_handler
 {
     echo "SORRY! I am not going down MUAHAHA!"
 }

 trap trap_handler SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP 

 while true
 do
      sleep 60
 done
```

So if I start this as a background task and try to kill it this is what happens:

```
 $ ps -ef | grep test &
 $ jobs
 [1]+  Running                 ./test_trap.sh &
 $ kill %1
 $ Terminated
 SORRY! I am not going down MUAHAH!

 $ jobs
 [1]+  Running                 ./test_trap.sh &
```

Ok, now let's monitor the process from a different terminal and watch what happens when I exit the terminal/shell the script was started from:

```
 $ pstree -clap 26163
 bash,26163
  └─test_trap.sh,26175 ./test_trap.sh
       └─sleep,26183 60
 ## exited the original terminal window with exit
 $ pstree -clap 26163
 $ 
 $ pstree -clap 26175
 test_trap.sh,26175 ./test_trap.sh
   └─sleep,26185 60
```

The terminal process does not exist anymore but when I do a pstree on the process ID for the test_trap.sh that was started, it and its sub processes are still there.

Comment: In the example above, where did your PID `26175` attach to when you exited the original terminal window? To PID `1`?

Comment: It attached to the parent "upstart" process which is under the current user session. if that goes away it will eventually be owned by the root process with pid 1.